# PHP Variable printing multiple variables

Tags: php, arrays, variables, for-loop

I have several variables, for example:

```
$q1
$q2
$q3
...
$q50
```

I would like to combine them info one variable who puts them info the VALUE of an INSERT INTO. Maybe a for loop?

```
INSERT INTO $table_name ($column_names) VALUES($q1, $q2, $q3)
```

So it might look like this

```
INSERT INTO $table_name ($column_names) VALUES($combined_variables)
```

This way, i could just manually add another variable to the $q51 and it would populate VALUE automaticly.

Is this possible? Maybe somehing like this (but this does not work)

```
$combined_variables = '';
for( $i = 1; $i <= 50 $i++ ) { 
    $combined_variables .= 'q' . $i . ', ';
}
$combined_variables = substr($combined_variables, 0, -2); //minus 2 to remove the last space and comma
```

Comment: a better idea would be dynamically building placeholders, then loading them up in a prepared statement

Comment: At a minimum get away from this ridiculousness and use an array.  Then just `implode`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [variable variables](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php) like this:

```
$combined_variables = array();
for ($i = 1; $i <= 50 $i++) { 
    $var = 'q' . $i;
    $combined_variables[] = ${$var};
}
$combined_variables = implode(', ', $combined_variables);
```

However, if you can use an array instead of 50 variables you'd have a much easier job.

Comment: Why do you use variable variables? I don't see why you would need them?!

Comment: He could just have the values in an array instead of variables.

Comment: @Savadon Just before you will ask a new question, you won't be able to use the variable `$combined_variables` in a insert query as you want right now

Comment: Take a look at the other answer, that's the correct one in this specific matter.

Answer (score 1):

This should work for you:

(Here I start with `$q1` and assign it to the array until the next `$qX` is not set)

```
<?php

    $combined_variables = [];
    $count = 1;

    while(isset(${"q" . $count})){
        $combined_variables[] = ${"q" . $count};
        $count++;
    }

?>
```

So as an example:

```
$q1 = 5;
$q2 = 2;
```

You would end up with following array:

```
Array ( [0] => 5 [1] => 2 )
```

And then you can simply use it in the query like this:

```
"INSERT INTO $table_name ($column_names) VALUES(" . "'" . implode("','", $combined_variables) . "'" . ")"
```